# Yii2 : how to echo parameters from searchModel

Tags: php, parameters, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

after i render `_search.php`  in `index.php`

I have used Kartik DateRange to to get data between tow dates .
here is my code  :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date', [
    'addon'=>['prepend'=>['content'=>'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>']],
    'options'=>['class'=>'drp-container form-group']
        ])->widget(DateRangePicker::classname(), [
            'useWithAddon'=>true
        ]);
 ?>
```

i used explode function to get the dates that i passed ,  and i get a real data , it works fine .
my searchModel code  :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\patientservices;

class patientservicesSearch extends patientservices
{

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id',  'price'], 'integer'],
        [['patient_id', 'doctor_id','service_id','date','state'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
public function scenarios()
{
    return Model::scenarios();
}

public function search($params)
{     
    $query = patientservices::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 150),
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {

      if ( ! is_null($this->date) && strpos($this->date, ' - ') !== false ) {
            list($start_date, $end_date) = explode(' - ', $this->date);
            $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'date', $start_date, $end_date]);
            $this->date = null;
            }  

        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->joinWith('patient');
    $query->joinWith('service');
    $query->joinWith('doctor');
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'patient_services.id' => $this->id,
        'patient_services.price' => $this->price,

    ]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like','patient.patient_name',$this->patient_id]);
    $query->orFilterWhere(['=','patient.patient_id',$this->patient_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like','services.service_name',$this->service_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like','doctors.doctor_name',$this->doctor_id]);
    if ( ! is_null($this->date) && strpos($this->date, ' - ') !== false ) {
           list($start_date, $end_date) = explode(' - ', $this->date);
           $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'date', $start_date, $end_date]);
           $this->date = null;
           }  

    $total = 0;
        if (!empty($dataProvider->getModels())) {
            foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $key => $val) {
                $total += $val->price;
            }
        }

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

after I  submit the form passing the parameters to `searchModel` and then as we know, then the date range become empty, The other fields do not become empty I need to echo the parameters that I passed to `searchModel` Especially the date range. i don't know what is my problem here  .

Comment: You can use a new model attribute for date range field and add the same to model's safe rule, Date range use separator to separate dates. You will need to explode string and use array items with between query

Comment: the date range works fine ,  and i did as you said  ,  but i need to echo the date range for the user as a report if he want to print it :\

Comment: you mean after hitting submit to a search when the results load the dateRange is empty and does not contain the entered date?

Comment: Yes , that's  it

Comment: can you add your `searchModel` that you are using for search ?

Comment: can you select the answer if it helped you out ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Sorry for delay , i was sick ,  but i doesn't help me , and i will update my question !

Comment: updated the answer see the edit you are setting the `$this->date=null` remove that line and it will fix and do mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks like is that your `date` value is not loading in the `searchModel` otherwise it would show up in the field even if you manually assign the value to the field like below just before you call the `view`. i am assuming the `searchModel` name as `ProductSearch`

```
$params['ProductSearch']['date']='2018-05-20 - 2018-05-23';
$dataProvider=$model->search($params);
$this->render('search',['model'=>$model]);
```

so go to your model and add the `date` field to your `safe` rules along with the other listed

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [ [ 'id' ] , 'integer' ] ,
        [ [ 'some_field', 'some_other_field', 'date' ] , 'safe' ] ,
    ];
}
```

and if this field is not a part of the database table and just created for search purpose then you should declare this field inside your `searchModel` as a public property of the class

```
public $date;
```

## `EDIT`

After the addition of the search model it seems you are setting the `date` field to `null` so it is obvious that it would not show you once it searches successfully, so inside your `search($params)` function at the end before you are calculating the `$total`, remove the line `$this->date=null;` from the condition

```
  $query->andFilterWhere(['like','doctors.doctor_name',$this->doctor_id]);
  if ( ! is_null($this->date) && strpos($this->date, ' - ') !== false ) {
       list($start_date, $end_date) = explode(' - ', $this->date);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'date', $start_date, $end_date]);

    //----->  $this->date = null;  //REMOVE THIS LINE //

  }
```